# how to parse a string to DateOnly using a specific format with .NET 8 IParsable<T>

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

In .Net 8, the `IParsable<T>` interface has `Parse` and `TryParse` methods but not `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact`. When parsing a `string` to `DateOnly`, I only want to accept strings in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. Is it possible to use `CultureInfo` to apply this restriction?

In my test code below, I wanted parsing to succeed for "2000-12-31" and fail for "2000/12/31" but both strings successfully parsed to `31 Dec 2000`.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create a culture that uses yyyy-MM-dd pattern for date parsing
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("");
            string[] datePatterns = new string[]
            {
                "yyyy-MM-dd",
            };
            char[] dateFormats = new char[]
            {
                'd',
                'D',
                'y',
            };
            foreach (char dateFormat in dateFormats)
            {
                culture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(datePatterns, dateFormat);
            }
            culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";

            // successfully parses to 31 Dec 2000
            DateOnly date1 = Parse<DateOnly>("2000-12-31", culture);

            // expected this to fail but it successfully parses to 31 Dec 2000
            DateOnly date2 = Parse<DateOnly>("2000/12/31", culture);
        }

        // helper method to force the use of IParsable<T>.Parse(...)
        static T Parse<T>(string s, IFormatProvider? provider)
            where T : IParsable<T>
        {
            T ret = T.Parse(s, provider);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Only want to accept strings in `yyyy-MM-dd`" and "use `CultureInfo` to apply this restriction" seem to contradict each other. If you want only `yyyy-MM-dd`, then check for that and only then pass to Date.Parse, with invariant culture. And if you want the passed culture info to decide what's parceable, then do that, but it won't be `yyyy-MM-dd` each time.

Comment: I don't necessarily want culture info to decide what is parsable but I don't see any other option when using `IParsable<T>.Parse(...)` because there is no `IParsable<T>.ParseExact(...)`

Comment: `Only want to accept strings` is a validation rule. You're trying to use `Parse` for validation, not just parsing. Why do you want to apply this in `DateOnly` and not in the code that has to read and convert those strings?

Comment: The title is misleading. _"I wanted parsing to succeed for "2000-12-31" and fail for "2000/12/31"_ is the _actual_ requirement. It has nothing to do with `IParsable` and such. It's a business rule. Don't try to over-generalize your code. Over-abstraction is also an anti-pattern.

Comment: BTW [DateOnly.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.tryparseexact?view=net-8.0) does exist. Why are you asking about `IParsable<T>` at all? Are you trying to abstract even the target type? Why?

Comment: This is definitely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if not an XYZ problem. You want to validate data (X) and think you need some custom Y mechanism (even though Data annotations already exist) and that new mechanism requires abstracting even the target type and a `IParsable.TryParseExact`. That doesn't exist, so you asked about Z, not the other two parts

Comment: I know that `DateOnly` has a `ParseExact` method but my question is whether it is possible to use `IParsable<T>` to parse an exact format when the interface does not have a `ParseExact` method. The sample code I posted is just a contrived example to illustrate what I am investigating.